# This test string is not supported: %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I ran my htaccess through a testing site after someone informed me the http/https part of it was broken. These are the errors that I received.

[image]

What am I able to do to fix this?

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; 
includeSubdomains;"
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Also, is there a way I can send all redirects not specified to one specific domain? Currently, I have about 80 hand-written redirects to specific pages, but I am to the point now where everything else can just go to the index. I have the redirects written like this.

```
Redirect /linear-motion /solution/linear-motion
Redirect /quiz /index
```

Is there something I can write at the bottom of this code to check for a redirect and if it doesn't have a specific redirect noted then send to index?

Comment: Perhaps the htaccess tester tool you are using doesn't support this condition.

Comment: @starkeen Do you see anything wrong with any of the code I put in my question? The person said this, "Http / Https issues are again part of your problem, that is what is busted." The code I posted is the only aspect that has the http/https.